# How to change activity by moving finger?

Tags: android, android-activity

I would like ask for help.
Can you give me an advice how to change activity by moving finger.(as the picture shows)
Thank you for answers

[image]

image:https://imageshack.us/download/661/xaxrzF.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using GestureDetector following is the working code replace left and right activity with your own activities

```html
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  private GestureDetector gesture;
  
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
  {
    gesture = new GestureDetector(new SwipeGestureDetector());
  }


  @Override
  public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) 
  {
    if (gesture.onTouchEvent(event)) 
 {
      return true;
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
  }

  private void onLeft() 
  {
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LeftActivity.class);
 startActivity(myIntent);
  }

  private void onRight() 
  {
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, RightActivity.class);
 startActivity(myIntent);
  }

  // Private class for gestures
  private class SwipeGestureDetector  extends SimpleOnGestureListener 
 {
  private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 120;
  private static final int SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH = 200;
  private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 200;

  @Override
  public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2,float velocityX, float velocityY) 
  {
   try 
   {
    float diffAbs = Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY());
    float diff = e1.getX() - e2.getX();

    if (diffAbs > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH)
    return false;
        
    // Left swipe
    if (diff > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE&& Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) 
    {
     MainActivity.this.onLeft();
    } 
    // Right swipe
    
    else if (-diff > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) 
    {
     MainActivity.this.onRight();
    }
   } 
   catch (Exception e) 
   {
    Log.e("MainActivity", "Error on gestures");
   }
   return false;
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: wdfeww if code is helpfull for you than kindly up vote my answer as well

Answer (score 3):

```
public class OnSwipeTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {

private final GestureDetector gestureDetector;
private SwipeGestureInterface gestureInterface;
private boolean left, right, top, bottom;
private boolean doubleTap;
private int x, y;

public OnSwipeTouchListener(Context ctx, boolean left, boolean right,
        boolean top, boolean bottom, boolean doubleTap,
        SwipeGestureInterface gestureInterface) {
    gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(ctx, new GestureListener());
    this.gestureInterface = gestureInterface;
    this.left = left;
    this.right = right;
    this.top = top;
    this.bottom = bottom;
    this.doubleTap = doubleTap;
}

private final class GestureListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

    private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 100;
    private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 120;

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        setX((int) e.getX());
        setY((int) e.getY());
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
            float velocityY) {
        boolean result = false;
        try {
            float diffY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
            float diffX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
            if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY)) {
                if (Math.abs(diffX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD
                        && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                    if (diffX > 0) {
                        onSwipeRight();
                    } else {
                        onSwipeLeft();
                    }
                }
                result = true;
            } else if (Math.abs(diffY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD
                    && Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                if (diffY > 0) {
                    onSwipeBottom();
                } else {
                    onSwipeTop();
                }
            }
            result = true;
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }

        Utils.log("onfling", "val Y:" + velocityY);
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (gestureInterface != null && doubleTap) {
            gestureInterface.onDoubleTap();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}

public void onSwipeRight() {
    if (gestureInterface != null && right)
        gestureInterface.onSwipeRight();
}

public void onSwipeLeft() {
    if (gestureInterface != null && left)
        gestureInterface.onSwipeLeft();
}

public void onSwipeTop() {
    if (gestureInterface != null && top)
        gestureInterface.onSwipeTop();
}

public void onSwipeBottom() {
    if (gestureInterface != null && bottom)
        gestureInterface.onSwipeBottom();
}

@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    return false;
}

public int getX() {
    return x;
}

public void setX(int x) {
    this.x = x;
}

public int getY() {
    return y;
}

public void setY(int y) {
    this.y = y;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
yourLayout.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

    int downX, upX;

     @Override
     public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

         if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
             downX = (int) event.getX(); 
             Log.i("event.getX()", " downX " + downX);
             return true;
         } 

         else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
             upX = (int) event.getX(); 
             Log.i("event.getX()", " upX " + downX);
             if (upX - downX > 100) {

                 // swipe right
                  //Call activity


             } 

             else if (downX - upX > -100) {

                 // swipe left
                 call activity
             }
             return true;

             }
             return false;
         }
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

Moving activity is not a good way. Use ViewPager to perform swiping.
Because when you will use activity then it will take time for switching while you will achieve it easily by fragment in view pager.

Please download code from below link and modify according to your need. 
https://github.com/JakeWharton/ViewPagerIndicator

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [ViewPage](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html) it best fits with what you are trying to do